# for-loop in python is blocked in the execution

Tags: python, mongodb, for-loop, pymongo

In this code I'm trying to join 2 collections in mongodb

- RM_Line contains 10 000 lines
- sflow contains 18 476 321 lines

With for-loop I insert the result of the aggregation in another collection and it gives me exactly 101 lines then it just block while executing without giving an error or stoping the execution

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["myevo"]
mycol = mydb["RM_Line"]
pipeline = [{'$lookup': 
                {'from' : 'sflow',
                 'localField' : 'IP_Adress',
                 'foreignField' : 'srcaddr',
                 'as' : 'mergeipadr'}},
            {'$unwind': '$mergeipadr'}, 
            { "$addFields": { "_id": "$$REMOVE" } }
             ]
mycol2 = mydb["RMLine_Merge_sflow"] 
merge = mycol.aggregate(pipeline)
for doc in (merge):
     mycol2.insert_one(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a lack of memory. Pipeline stages have a limit of [100 megabytes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions) of RAM

To allow for the handling of large datasets, use the [allowDiskUse](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-external-sort) option to enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.